# Tkinter window swapping

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know much about python or Tkinter but my functions aren't firing. No errors but No result either.

```
from tkinter import *


def root_win():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('700x400+100+100')
    root.maxsize(700, 400)
    root.minsize(700, 400)
    root.title("root")

    btn1_root = Button(root, text="ext1", command=lambda: [root.destroy, ext1_win])
    btn1_root.place(x=590, y=360, height=30, width=100)
    btn1_root.configure(bg="DodgerBlue3", fg="black")


def ext1_win():

    ext1 = Tk()
    ext1.geometry('700x400+100+100')
    ext1.maxsize(700, 400)
    ext1.minsize(700, 400)
    ext1.title("1")

    btn1_ext1 = Button(ext1, text="back", command=lambda: [ext1.destroy, root_win])
    btn1_ext1.place(x=590, y=360, height=30, width=100)
    btn1_ext1.configure(bg="DodgerBlue3", fg="black")


root_win()
```

I'm trying to make it so I can hop between different windows to conserve screen space when I start putting together the rest of my project. Tkinter doesn't seem to like all of def root_win(): being a def.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `lambda`, you need to call the functions inside the body of the lambda.

```
btn1_ext1 = Button(ext1, text="back", command=lambda: [root.destroy(), ext1_win()])
```

You also need to call `mainloop`. With the above code your functions will be called, but they just run to completion and then exit.

```
def root_win():

    root = Tk()
    ...
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I understand. But that doesn't fix the problem of root_win() not running.

Comment: @Josh: you also need to call `mainloop`. The functions _are_ running, it's just that they run to the end and then return since you don't call `mainloop`.

Answer (score 0):

In Line 12, change this:

```
btn1_root = Button(root, text="ext1", command=lambda: [root.destroy, ext1_win])
```

to:

```
btn1_root = Button(root, text="ext1", command=ext1_win)
```

Output you can see `root.title("root")`:

[image]

Output you can see `ext1.title("1"`:

[image]